# Matplotlib in python | connecting dots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

What is the possible way to connect dots I needed?

Here is part of my code for you to understand what I mean:

```py
x = [0, 5, 10, 15, 100, 105, 110, 115]
y = [15, 10, 5, 0, 115, 110, 105, 100]
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))

plt.xlim(-1, 120)
plt.ylim(-1, 120)
plt.grid()      

plt.plot(x, y, 'og-')
```

Have this:

[image: Connected points]

But I have to connect those grouped dots from `(0, 15)` to `(15, 0)` and `(100, 115)` to `(115, 100)` *only*. I do not need that long connection between the dots: `(15, 0)` to `(100, 115)`

[image: Illustration of the connection]

Can anyone help find a solution for this problem?

Comment: It's not a mind reader.  When you give it a series of points, there is no way for it to determine one segment should not be drawn.  Separating the segments is YOUR job.

Comment: Oh, you want to drop lines segments that exceed a certain length.  I think there's an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

draw the lines you want, and don't draw the ones you don't:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
#x = [0, 5, 10, 15, 100, 105, 110, 115]
#y = [15, 10, 5, 0, 115, 110, 105, 100]

plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))

plt.xlim(-1, 120)
plt.ylim(-1, 120)
plt.grid()   

x1 = [0, 5, 10, 15]
y1 = [15, 10, 5, 0]

x2 = [100, 105, 110, 115]
y2 = [115, 110, 105, 100]


plt.plot(x1, y1, 'og-')
plt.plot(x2,y2, 'og-')

plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Imagine you have a very big array.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a very long x-array, you can combine numpy's [`np.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) with [`np.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) to calculate the indices.  `np.diff` would calculate the subsequent differences, which can be compared to a threshold.  `np.nonzero` will return all indices where the comparison results in `True`.  Looping through these indices lets you draw each part separately.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [0, 5, 10, 15, 100, 105, 110, 115]
y = [15, 10, 5, 0, 115, 110, 105, 100]
threshold = 20
indices = np.nonzero(np.diff(x) >= threshold)[0] + 1

for i0, i1 in zip(np.append(0, indices), np.append(indices, len(x))):
    plt.plot(x[i0:i1], y[i0:i1], '-go')
plt.show()
```

Here is a more elaborate example:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 30
x = (np.random.randint(1, 5, N) * 5).cumsum()
y = np.random.randint(0, 10, N) * 5
plt.plot(x, y, 'r--') # this is how the complete line would look like
threshold = 20
indices = np.nonzero(np.diff(x) >= threshold)[0] + 1
for i0, i1 in zip(np.append(0, indices), np.append(indices, len(x))):
    plt.plot(x[i0:i1], y[i0:i1], '-go')
plt.show()
```

[image: drawing a line in pieces]

Comment: Thank you, will think about it.